# How to execute a test function all time?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I want to create a command prompt simulation in python, but I have run into
an issue. Indeed, when I type the commands in my Entry, nothing happend whereas It
should execute the functions that I created in the code. So, I guess that the problem
is that my tests functions are not running all time, but even when I run them in a while True
loop, It still does not work. If someone could help me, I would be happy. Thanks.

So, here is the code :

```
from tkinter import *
import time

bgColor = "black"

window = Tk()
window.title("Cmd")
window.geometry("720x480")
window.configure(bg=bgColor)

commandShow = Label(window, text=None, font=("Courrier", 10), bg="black", fg="lime")
commandShow.place(x=4, y=30)

def printCommandUser(event):
    textCommand = str(entrée1.get())
    commandShow.config(text=None)
    commandShow.config(text=str(entrée1.get()))
    return textCommand

def changeBg():
    if entrée1.get() == "/bgcolor":
        textChangeBg = Label(window, text="Type the color of the background below", font=("Courrier", 10), bg="black", fg="lime")
        textChangeBg.place(x=4, y=50)
        bgColor = str(entrée1.get())
        window.config(bg=bgColor)
        print(bgColor)

def shutdownCmd():
    if entrée1.get() == "/shutdown":
        window.destroy()

welcomeText = Label(window, text="Welcome in your cmd ! (Type below)", font=("Courrier", 10), bg="black", fg="lime")
welcomeText.place(x=4, y=10)


indicationEntrée = Label(window, text="Press Enter \nto execute", font=("Courrier", 8), bg="black", fg="lime")
indicationEntrée.place(x=630, y=440)

entrée1 = Entry(window, width=100, bg="lime")
entrée1.place(x=4, y=450)

run = True

while run:
    changeBg()
    shutdownCmd()
    window.bind("<Return>", printCommandUser)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `window.mainloop()` doesn't return until you exit the Tkinter application, so your loop doesn't repeat. You should call the test function in `printCommandUser()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the code as posted. I have attempted to cover some of the bigger points here, and I produced a much more maintainable version, which I think you can use as a starting point for adding much more functionality.

The issues that jump out at me in the original code:

- The `changeBg` function creates a new label over and over, but no reference is saved to it, so you may need to move that to a global scope
- The `changeBg` and `shutdownCmd` functions are called randomly, when the user hasn't had time to input anything (in the beginning of the while loop)
- The function `printCommandUser` that executes when the user hits Enter doesn't check to see what functions to execute, so the other functionality is never used. Adding some handling of the user input to that function can get this script alot further.
- The while loop doesn't do anything meaningful, it will immediate get stuck on the `window.mainloop` call, and that shouldn't be recalled after a user has shut the window down anyways, so the loop as a whole should be removed, and `window.mainloop` called once.
- There is no way to track if a user input the `/bgcolor` command and the next input should be the color, nor is there any way to process a more complex command like `/bgcolor black`, at least one of them should be there.
- Recommendation, store reused things once and then reference them, like the font and font size, so that you can change it once for the whole program at once.
- Recommendation, `Widget.place` is very challenging to use. I highly recommend you look into `Widget.pack` or `Widget.grid` which tend to be much easier to work with as your GUI's become more complex.
- Recommendation, wrap your GUI up in a class. As written, it cannot be imported by someone's else's module very easily, and will immediately start running upon import, which is unlikely to be the intended functionality.

Here is what I recommend to implement what I see in your script. I added a few small tidbits here and there, and tried to put plenty of comments to explain my thinking.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst


# Wrapped the functionality in a class to make it a little cleaner
#   and much easier to import from another script
class CmdSim:
    # Save these at the class level so that they can be referenced and
    #   consistent across the whole GUI
    bgColor = "black"
    window_geom = "720x480"
    font_large = ("Courrier", 10)
    font_small = ("Courrier", 8)
    line_indicator = '>> '

    def __init__(self, master):
        # master is a tkinter.Tk() and the parent window
        self._master = master
        # Configure the columns to make them stretch out to the whole geometry
        self._master.columnconfigure(0, weight=10, uniform='mastercol')
        self._master.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform='mastercol')
        self._master.title('Cmd')
        self._master.geometry(CmdSim.window_geom)
        # Set the default background color
        self._master.configure(bg=CmdSim.bgColor)
        # This is the top part, that shows prior inputs and outputs
        self._cmd_hist = tkst.ScrolledText(
            self._master, font=CmdSim.font_large, bg='black', fg='lime'
        )
        self._cmd_hist.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='news')
        # Set the starting text
        self._cmd_hist.insert(tk.END, 'Welcome in your cmd ! (Type below)\n')
        # The input where the user types
        self._input_box = tk.Entry(
            self._master, font=CmdSim.font_large, bg='lime', fg='black'
        )
        self._input_box.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='news')
        # The label indicating how to use the input box
        self._input_hint = tk.Label(
            self._master, text='Press Enter\nto execute',
            font=CmdSim.font_small, bg='black', fg='lime'
        )
        self._input_hint.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='news')
        # When a two part command is entered, track that the input is pending
        #   another input argument
        self._pending_cmd = None
        # Track if a shutdown should be executed after the input processing
        self._pending_shutdown = False
        # Capture key presses so that focus goes back to input and enter
        #   presses are appropriately handled
        self._master.bind('<Key>', self._proc_keys)
        # Focus the input box so it's ready to go right away
        self._proc_keys()

        # A lookup for all the commands and their appropriate functions
        #   to execute
        self._commands = {
            '/bgcolor': self._changebg,  # "/bgcolor" or "/bgcolor black"
            '/shutdown': self._shutdown  # "/shutdown"
        }

    def _proc_input(self):
        # Process all the inputs provided when the user presses enter
        # Retrieve the input
        input_command = self._input_box.get().rstrip()
        # Reset the input box
        self._input_box.delete(0, 'end')
        # Init a string to put in the history
        cmd_out = ''
        # If a pending command is active, send the input to that function
        if self._pending_cmd:
            # Store the user input
            cmd_out += ' ' + input_command + '\n'
            # Execute the function
            cmd_out += self._pending_cmd(input_command)
        else:
            # If there is no pending command, process this as a new one
            # Add the user input to the history
            cmd_out += CmdSim.line_indicator + input_command + '\n'
            # Find the command in the commands lookup
            if input_command.split()[0] in self._commands:
                # Execute the appropriate command and add teh return
                #   to the history
                cmd_out += self._commands[input_command.split()[0]](
                    input_command
                )
            else:
                # Let the user know the command was no recognized
                cmd_out += 'Unrecognized command'
        cmd_out += '\n'
        # Add the new history lines to the history box
        self._cmd_hist.insert(tk.END, cmd_out)
        # Scroll to the end so that the new data is visible
        self._cmd_hist.see(tk.END)
        # If the user requested a shutdown, do it
        if self._pending_shutdown:
            self._master.destroy()

    def _changebg(self, input_command: str) -> str:
        # The function to execute /bgcolor
        # If this function was already called without a color then process
        #   the color on the following input
        if self._pending_cmd:
            # Reset the pending command since it's now being processed
            self._pending_cmd = None
            try:
                # Set the background color
                self._cmd_hist.configure(bg=input_command)
            except tk.TclError as e:
                # If the user typed in some random color, let them know
                if 'unknown color name' in str(e):
                    return 'Unknown color name!'
                else:
                    raise
            # If it was successful, report that in the history
            return 'Color changed to ' + input_command
        else:
            # If this is a fresh /bgcolor call, split it to see if a color
            #   was already provided
            split_in = input_command.split()
            # If more than two are present, give up, back input
            if len(split_in) > 2:
                return 'Bad arguments'
            # If a color argument was passed in or not we will process
            #   it the same way, either recursively call this function
            #   to process the argument, or leave it waiting for more
            #   user input
            self._pending_cmd = self._changebg
            # Inform the user that they still need to provide a color
            if len(split_in) == 1:
                return 'Type the color of the background below'
            # The user put the argument in with the /bgcolor call
            #   so recall this function to process it
            return self._changebg(split_in[1])

    def _shutdown(self, input_command: str):
        # Indicate to shutdown after finishing processing user input
        self._pending_shutdown = True
        return ''

    def _proc_keys(self, e=None):
        # If a key was pressed and was Ctrl key ignore
        #   this allows the user to copy from the history
        if e is not None and e.keycode == 17:
            return
        # Put the focus in the input box instead of taking the input
        self._input_box.focus()
        # If the user presses enter, process the input
        if e is not None and e.keycode == 13:
            self._proc_input()


def _main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    cs = CmdSim(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

And here is what it looks like, which is quite similar to what you were looking for I believe:
[image: Sample usage screenshot]